# Sending UDP packets continuously in the background from a Java app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets, flask

I want to send button states, joystick values, and other data continuously in the background to a python flask server using Datagram. For now receiving only one time, I have used a Java client to send data, the code is given below.
I will be grateful if someone answers what should I add or remove from the client or receiver to get data continuously in the background. Thank you.

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class UDP_Client {
    public String Message;

    @SuppressLint({"NewApi", "StaticFieldLeak"})
    public void sendUDP() {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> async_cient = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try (DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket()) {
                        DatagramPacket dp;
                        dp = new DatagramPacket(Message.getBytes(), Message.length(), InetAddress.getByName("192.168.x.xxx"), 3000);
                        ds.setBroadcast(true);
                        ds.send(dp);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        };

        async_cient.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
}
```

and my Flask server

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.x.xxx"
UDP_PORT = 3000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(3000)
    print("Received message:", data)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you only want this to happen when the game is running and in the foreground (anything long term in the background is dicey on Android).  That said, you should not be using AsyncTask for this.  The class is deprecated to begin with, but even without that it was a bad fit.  Instead, spin up a HandlerThread and send a message to the handler whenever you want to send a packet with the data to send.  When you want to end the thread, you can send a special END_THREAD message.